# Compare two dataframe colums and add them to the dataframe

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataframe with two columns. I want to add a new colume to `df` where all the values are inside, were the dataframe matches with the first colume.

I tried:

```
df<-data.frame(A=c("1","test","2","3",NA,"Test", NA),B=c("1","No Match","No Match","3",NA,"Test", "No Match"))

df[df$A == df$B ]
```

However, I get:

```
Error in Ops.factor(df$A, df$B) : level sets of factors are different
```

Any recommednation what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with `NA` first and then add your column:

```
> df[is.na(df)]=""
> df$New = with(df, A==B)
> df
     A        B   New
1    1        1  TRUE
2 test No Match FALSE
3    2 No Match FALSE
4    3        3  TRUE
5                TRUE
6 Test     Test  TRUE
7      No Match FALSE
```

Or remove `NA` from your initial `data.frame` with `df = df[complete.cases(df),]` and then add the column.

If you really want to have `False` when there is `NA` in A or B column:

```
> transform(df, New=ifelse(is.na(A)|is.na(B), FALSE, df$A==df$B))
     A        B   New
1    1        1  TRUE
2 test No Match FALSE
3    2 No Match FALSE
4    3        3  TRUE
5 <NA>     <NA> FALSE
6 Test     Test  TRUE
7 <NA> No Match FALSE
```

Comment: Thx for our answer! I would do, if its NA then I do `false`. Any How could this second if be added?

Comment: Are you using the same `df` as in the example?  It gives the error as the OP mentioned or else you have to specify the need for `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the `data.frame`

Comment: I am using the same df. @mrquad, there is a version dealing with NA if you really want to.

Comment: For some reason, I get the same error as the OP.  I am using R 3.1.2.

Comment: Interesting, I am using version  `3.1.0 (2014-04-10)`. `Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)`

Comment: For what it's worth, I get the OP's error also with R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit).  there are also choices of na.omit and na.exclude (to filter or remove, respectively)